# When Item is selected from Combo Box, some element with Combo Box Light Dismiss is getting generated - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, horizontal-scrolling

On one of the XAML Pages, I have 3 combo boxes on left side and ListView with Horizontal Scroll on the right.

The three combo boxes are not cascading combo boxes. If I click any of the three combo boxes, under "PopupRoot", some ComboBoxLightDismiss gets generated which has width and height of the entire screen. This leave my screen in the hang state as this is some invisible canvas. I am not able to figure out the reason for this.

**Visual Tree before Combo box Click**
[image: Visual Tree before Combo box Click]

**Visual Tree after Combo Box is click or any item is selected**
[image: Visual Tree after Combo Box is click or any item is selected]

I am adding the XAML code for the left User Control of the combo boxes as well the page below:

**UserControl XAML Code which includes 3 Combo Boxes**

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockSourceLabel" Text="Source" Margin="0,6,6,6" Style="{StaticResource LeftNavTextBlock}"/>
<ComboBox Height="30" x:Name="comboBoxSourceName" Margin="0,6,6,6" FontSize="14"
              Style="{StaticResource NewComboBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NewComboBoxItem}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Codes,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding SourceFile.FeedCode,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                  
              Width="250">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <awbehaviors:ComboBoxKeyboardSelection/>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadSelectedSourceCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxSourceName}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockFiscalMonthLabel" Text="Calendar Month" Margin="0,6,6,6" Style="{StaticResource LeftNavTextBlock}" />
<ComboBox Height="30" x:Name="comboBoxFileFiscalMonth" FontSize="14"  Margin="0,6,6,6" Width="250"  ItemsSource="{Binding MonthNames}"   
              DisplayMemberPath="Item1" SelectedValue="{Binding SourceFile.CalendarMonth,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedValuePath="Item2" Style="{StaticResource NewComboBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NewComboBoxItem}">
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockFiscalYearLabel"  Margin="0,6,6,6"  Text="Calendar Year" Style="{StaticResource LeftNavTextBlock}"/>
<ComboBox Height="30" x:Name="comboxBoxFileFiscalYear" Margin="0,6,6,6" FontSize="14"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Years,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding SourceFile.CalendarYear,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              Style="{StaticResource NewComboBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NewComboBoxItem}"
              Width="250"></ComboBox>
```

**XAML code for Page which includes the ListView and UserControl**

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" x:Name="gridLayout" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#FFADB9CA">
        <UserControls:FeedInformation DataContext="{Binding FeedInformationVM}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Row1}" Background="{StaticResource gridcontainerBackGroundBrush}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*" x:Name="GridRow"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" x:Name="GridColumn"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="titleGrid">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NewHeaderTextStyle}" Text="{Binding FeedSourceFileStatus.FileName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None"
                    Margin="12,25,50,25" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=GridRow}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SubItemsCollection, ElementName=pgControl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LvItemStyle}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView  SelectionMode="None" IsZoomedInView="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False"  x:Name="ListRow" Tag="{Binding RowNo}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding FeedData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LvItemStyle}" AllowDrop="True"                
                                ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"  CanDragItems="{Binding RowNo, Converter={StaticResource ListInttoBooleanConverter}}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid  Height="35" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                        <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="1 1 0.3 1" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False"   Opacity="0.5"
                                            Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource RowNotoVisibilityConverter4}, ElementName=ListRow}" 
                                                Fill="#FF9DC3E6"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FeedCellData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                FontSize="12" LineHeight="13" Foreground="{StaticResource TaxHubItemForegroundBrush}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Width="120" AllowDrop="True"  Padding="5,1,1,1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="{Binding Tag, ElementName=ListRow}"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding FeedCellData}"                               
                                                Height="{Binding Tag, Converter={StaticResource RowtoHeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsStackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I don't seem to figure out the reason for this canvas getting generated when combobox is clicked.

**Note: This application is moved from Win 8.1 App to Win 10 UWP app. This seems to be working fine in the 8.1 app which is made compatible with win 10 but this problem is coming from using this in UWP**

After debugging, I realized that this is happening because of using **VirtualizingStackPanel** in the outer ListView. In my ListView, every row has 200 columns. When I removed **VirtualizingStackPanel**, horizontal scroll bar for the whole List doesnt appear and I am not able to move horizontally. Does anybody can help with this?